# Automated UI test association in Azure DevOps doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, testing, azure-devops, ui-automation, testcafe

I am writing automated UI tests using TestCafe framework. And it needs to associate the test.js file with a TestCase in Azure DevOps to run pipelines and for receiving reports in Test Plan > Progress report. But somehow I can not associate test.js file with a TestCase because the VisualStudio doesn't sees it

Have followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops
But was stuck at "Associate to Test Case" point.
Somehow, after solution(project) was build in Visual Studio and "Run All" button at Test Explorer was clicked - the system says that no tests was found.
[image]

I have added unit.js file just to check if everything works in general - and the system has found it.
[image]
But not UI test.js file.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? What am I missing?
Glad to any response!

Comment: Could you please share a sample VS solution that demonstrates the issue along with the steps to reproduce the error? I need to be able to reproduce the problematic behavior on my side to investigate it.

Comment: Hi, @vasily.strelyaev thank you for your help!
1. Clone this repo to a Visual Studio Community https://github.com/MariyaQA/TestCafeChecking.git 
2. Open folder with the project
3. Terminal -“npm install”
4. Open Test Explorer
5. Build the solution just in case
6. Select “Run all tests” at Test Explorer
Actual result: you will see 0 tests and a Warning - No test is available in E:\path\to\your\project

Sometimes the system sees unit test, sometimes - doesn't see it. I am not so good at unit tests and I am searching for an answer about UI part. So thank you again for involve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance to Microsoft Dev Community - there is no way for now to perform such bond - to use Azure DevOps with JavaScript tools and language. So thank you for involve!